# Debugging data in 'anonymous namespaces' (C++)

Tags: c++, namespaces, debugging

Recently, I got a crash dump file from a customer.  I could track the problem down to a class that could contain incorrect data, but I only got a void-pointer to the class, not a real pointer (void-pointer came from a window-property, therefore it was a void-pointer).
Unfortunately, the class to which I wanted to cast the pointer to, was in an anonymous namespace, like this:

```
namespace
   {
   class MyClass
      {
      ...
      };
   }

...
void *ptr = ...
// I know ptr points to an instance of MyClass,
// and at this location I want to cast ptr to (MyClass *) in the debugger.
```

When I use `ptr` in the watch window, Visual Studio 2005 just shows the pointer value.
If I use `(MyClass *)ptr`, the debugger tells me it cannot cast to it.

How can I cast `ptr` to a `MyClass` pointer?

Note: I could eventually use a silly-named namespace (like the name of the source file), and then use a "using namespace", but I would expect better solutions.

Comment: Btw, VS 2008 exhibits the same problem.  I'd recommend sending MS themselves a note.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a(VS.80).aspx).  It doesn't look like there's a nice solution within the Watch window (you can get the decorated name of your class from a listing I guess).

Your "silly-named namespace" idea would work okay, you could also just declare an identical class with a silly name and cast to that type instead.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing anonymous namespaces in Visual Studio Debugger's expressions is not supported (at least as of VS 2017) and it's really annoying.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger#c-expressions

> Anonymous namespaces are not supported. If you have the following code, you cannot add **test** to the watch window:
>
> ```
> namespace mars
> {   
>     namespace  
>     {  
>         int test = 0;   
>     }   
> }   
> int main()   
> {   
>     // Adding a watch on test does not work.   
>     mars::test++;   
>     return 0;   
> }
> ```