# How to set breakpoint by function name inside anonymous namespace in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints

I have the following code:

```
namespace
{
    void Foo()
    {
    }
}

namespace Bar
{
    void Foo()
    {
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo();
    Bar::Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to put breakpoint on `Foo()` inside anonymous namespace by name (Ctrl+B key binding). I can do it for function inside named namespace `Bar` with no problem by name `Bar::Foo`. I tried `anonymous namespace::Foo` for anonymous namespace but VS fails to parse this name, i guess because of whitespace character in name. Also I tried to put different quotation marks but with no luck. Is it possible at all to put this breakpoint?

Comment: Dunno, but you can try to define a type inside the function and output its name using `typeid(T).name` (you need to include `<typeinfo>` header), and possibly there you'll see how the function is meant to be referred to.

Comment: In gdb, the command to set a breakpoint is: b (anonymous namespace)::xxClass::xxFunction(xxType&..). I don't known whether it works in VisualStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem a long time ago ([Debugging data in 'anynomous namespaces' (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334989/debugging-data-in-anynomous-namespaces-c)).  I wanted to look at the value of a data member in an unnamed namespace, but I couldn't get this done.

Finally, somebody pointed me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a%28VS.80%29.aspx.  Maybe you can get the decorated function name and put a breakpoint on that.

Comment: Yes, this helped. I've got decorated function name using `dumpbin.exe /symbols breakpoits.obj` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285(v=vs.80).aspx) and put breakpoint on it. Looks like there is no other way to it in VS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Visual Studio can't set breakpoint by function name inside anonymous namespace. Even WinDbg can't do this.

If you have sources you can set breakpoint by line.

Comment: It is possible to do it by decorated function name. See my comments in another answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I set breakpoint to ?Foo@?A0xac6cc1fe@@YAXXZ. I have tried this before but I missed first ? symbol.