# How to set a breakpoint in gdb for an anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, gdb

In my code base, there are some callbacks functions which are defined in anonymous namespace. I am debugging in gdb and I want to set breakpoint in the function using function name. 
I also tried putting breakpoint by using filename : linenum , but that will generally work if the file is already loaded or else it will say 
"No source file found"
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n

So, the workaround is that once the debugger is inside the same file, I can set breakpoint using filename : line number

But is there any other way to set breakpoints inside anonymous namespace ?

Related stackoverflow questions :
[How to set breakpoint by function name inside anonymous namespace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388104/how-to-set-breakpoint-by-function-name-inside-anonymous-namespace-in-visual-stud)

But this does not solve the problem over here.

As per some post in stackoverflow,

1. I tried using 
   ::function_name()
   but this does not work.
2. anonymous namespace::function_name()

namespace 
{
    int function_name(int a, int b)
    {
       return a+b;
    }
}

"No source file found"
/root/workspace/ProtocolInterface.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Even if the breakpoint pending, it does not break at the mentioned function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think anonymous namespace must be in parentheses.

```
(gdb) b (anonymous namespace)::function_name
```

It worked for me, please give it a try.